# Check if a value exists in between a key and its value in hash table

Tags: java, hashtable, contains

How to check if a value exists in between a key and its value in hash table?

I want to check if a value is present in hash table or in between any of the key and its value

I used the following code to check if a value is present as a key or value

```
if(table.containsKey(val) || table.containsValue(val))
```

But how to check if it is present in between any of the key and its corresponding value?

Comment: Can you clarify "*in between any of the key and its corresponding value*"?

Comment: @user2133404     Seems to me like iterator issue; if you know how to use them.

Comment: Suppose if the value is 6. 
If the hash table contains a key 5 and value 8, it should return true

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: @user2133404 what you want here. I got in this way you want to find hash table key where value= x and find hash table value where key =x. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to flatten out the map and check if a given value is contained in the range between the lowest key or value and the largest key or value.

You could put all the keys and values in [a `SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), for example a `TreeSet`, which has the `first()` and `last()` methods to retrieve the lowest / highest item.

It could look like this:

```
SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<> ();
set.addAll(map.keySet());
set.addAll(map.values());

//return true if input within the range
return (input >= set.first() || input <= set.last());
```

You could populate the set in parallel with the map for efficiency to avoid recreating a set for every query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Iterate the HashTable
2. store the key and value in diff temp
3. Then compare the value in between the tempkey and tempvalue

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> boolean hasValueBetween(Map<T, T> map, T value) {
    for(Map.Entry<T, T> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().compareTo(value) <= 0 && entry.getValue().compareTo(value) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```